# How can I activate Shape in Tree tool?

Tags: modeling

It seems that Shape option is not activate. How can I activate it?

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: I think ur using older version

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using an improved version of Sapling that can be download from GitHub:
https://github.com/abpy/improved-sapling-tree-generator/archive/master.zip

Also, you can find this manual and presets useful too:
https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?395082-Blender-Sapling-Tree-Tutorial-%2528free-download%2529

Comment: Thank you Jan. Please can you tell me how download it?

Comment: I tried the link that you sent me but I don't have any idea how to do it. Sorry. Can you help me?

Comment: Download the zip and copy the folder "add_curve_sapling_3" into your Blender addons folder. If you use Windows it is located in C:/Users/your-username/AppData/Roaming/Blender Foundation/Blender/2.78/scripts/addons
Then you need to activate the addon in the Blender, it's name is "Sapling_3". Also disable the old Sapling addon.

Comment: I have Mac. How to open add_curve_sapling_3 in Blender? Many thanks

Comment: Ok. I did it. Many but many thanks. Have a good evening.

Comment: Does this improved Sapling work for you? Is that Shape option enabled? I am glad I could help you! Good evening for you too :)

Comment: Sorry, it is not working. I have the same problem as before. Why? I diablee the old Sapling addon.

Comment: So you select Add -> Curve -> Add Tree 3.1 and you don't have the Shape select enabled?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49750/discussion-between-meri-and-jan-kaderabek).